# A Lot of .so files (1268 files) are seen in default storage in my android phone

Tags: internal-storage, custom-roms

I have Lenovo A390, rooted and installed a custom ROM. I have been using this ROM for 4 months but recently I am seeing these `lib` files. Refer the sample screenshot. It keep generating after using sometime.
Default storage or junk files saved in SD card Home directory - /mnt/sdcard
Please let me know if any other info needed and tell me how to get rid of these files permanently. Also phone started responding slow and I am maintaining 50% free space in both SD card and phone storage.

Custom ROM - http://www.needrom.com/download/a390-xperia-v5-0-honami-z2/

[image: list of .so files]

Comment: Have you tried googling some of the file names? A quick check shows some of these related to GAPPS Google Apps Minimal Edition. Has this been recently installed?

Comment: What is "default storage"? In which path/directory do you see those files? What custom ROM have you installed? Which Android version?

Comment: [`.so` files are native shared libraries](http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/concepts.html) used by some apps. If you remove them, the offended apps won't work properly. Also, they don't make your phone slow. The cause of your device slowing down is not these files.

Comment: where are those .so files located ? on sdcard ? in /data partition ? and did u use link2SD ?

Comment: @wbogacz I didn't try googling the file names and also I didn't install google related apps recently.

Comment: @AndrewT. After clearing these files, I am not seeing any change in phone behavior. Common Issue I face before/after file removal is - Slow response. Example - Dial screen takes 15 to 45 secs  to show up.

Comment: @Whereismymind That much of a lag can't be caused by .so files. They are just libraries. Still, you haven't told the exact location of those files within your phone.

Comment: @SarpSTA - I have updated in summary "Default storage or junk files saved in SD card Home directory - /mnt/sdcard "